# Implementation of sigmoid function as input in simulink

Tags: input, simulink, sigmoid

I am supposed to use a sigmoid function as an input for a cruise controller system with an integrator controller. I tried to find the Laplace transform for the function but i could not find any. Furthermore I tried to find a block for sigmiod in simulink but there was not any.